# Ionic 2 prevent hardware back button default

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

How can I prevent default navigation when pressing hardware back button? I've tried `registerBackButtonAction`, but then it overwrites behavior of back button in every page which I don't want.

This didn't help either.

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
  }, false);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you can see in [Ionic docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/Platform/#registerBackButtonAction) `registerBackButtonAction` returns a function:

> A function that, when called, will unregister its back button
>   action.

So you can use that function to restore the default behavior when leaving the page, like this:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    // Property used to store the callback of the event handler to unsubscribe to it when leaving this page
    public unregisterBackButtonAction: any;

    constructor(...) { ... }

    ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.initializeBackButtonCustomHandler();
    }

    ionViewWillLeave() {
        // Unregister the custom back button action for this page
        this.unregisterBackButtonAction && this.unregisterBackButtonAction();
    }

    public initializeBackButtonCustomHandler(): void {
        this.unregisterBackButtonAction = this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
            this.customHandleBackButton();
        }, 10);
    }

    private customHandleBackButton(): void {
        // do what you need to do here ...
    }
}
```

So as you can see, the key is to store the callback of the `registerBackButtonAction` method and use it later when leaving the page (or when you want to restore the default behavior):

```
this.unregisterBackButtonAction = this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
    this.customHandleBackButton();
}, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I had a thought about storing it somehow like ordinal handlers for event listeners but I didn't know how to unregister them when leaving.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped :)

Comment: Would love to see the TypeScript version of the same

Comment: thanks for your solution, but with my need to double click on the hardware back button restore back button default behavior. please, how could I handle this?