# How to navigate to page when android back button pressed in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

I have created an application using Ionic 2 Framework. I have used custom back button in my application to navigate to appropriate pages. But When I press back button in my android phone it navigates to previous page which is not relevent to what I have mentioned to navigate. Is there any solution to navigate to the same page when press back button both in application and device.

Comment: Probbly you should use navController instead of nav, because nav set root page and every thing before this delete from stack. but is better that up your code for more help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic 2 prevent hardware back button default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42483627/ionic-2-prevent-hardware-back-button-default)

Comment: I've added the link of a similar question. There you can see how to customize what happens when the user uses the physical back button.

Answer (score 0):

Inject Platform from 'ionic-angular' and then register a new handler to the back button action:

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(private platform: Platform) { }

ionViewWillEnter(): void {
    this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => this.backButtonFunc());
}

private backButtonFunc(): void {
     // do something 
}
```