# Disable mobile hardware back button in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

We have been working on a business application and facing a very strange issue. Whenever we press the mobile hardware back button, application GUI gets disturbed. We have already spent a lot man hours on this problem but issue is still there.

I was thinking about to disable back button but I don't know how to do it in ionic 2. Could anybody tell me how can I disable hardware back button in ionic 2 or angular ?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42489325/3710630

Comment: @Mansoor, checkout this article https://www.gajotres.net/ionic-2-3-how-to-manage-hardware-back-button-event-like-a-pro/

Comment: I have the same issue with a cordova (not ionic) app and I also deactivated the backbutton. I suspect that this has to do with caching, but I'mn not sure. There is a cordova plugin to disable webview caching, you might want to try it (it did not work for me though: https://github.com/kroodle/cordova-disable-http-cache)

Comment: Can we disable url in ionic ?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, I don't think it is a good idea to disable or override native functionality as it could confuse the user, but it should be possible to define custom behavior for the back button using the `registerBackButtonAction` method in the Platform API:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#registerBackButtonAction

Answer (score 0):

You can use `registerBackButtonAction`

Read Ionic Device [**Document**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#registerBackButtonAction)

```
import { App } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public  app: App) {}

this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
    let nav = app.getActiveNavs()[0];
    if (nav.canGoBack()){ //Can we go back?
        nav.pop();
    } else {
        const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'App termination',
            message: 'Do you want to close the app?',
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Cancel',
                role: 'cancel',
                handler: () => {
                    console.log('Application exit prevented!');
                }
            },{
                text: 'Close App',
                handler: () => {
                    this.platform.exitApp(); // Close this application
                }
            }]
        });
        alert.present();
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually, I have already tried this option. We can capture the register event but don't how to prevent it going back.

Comment: Can we disable URL in ionic 2 ? When we navigate, url gets change. But can we prevent it to change? I mean rather than this http://localhost:8100/#/somepage ,  can we make it just http://localhost:8100 ?

Comment: still having the same problem :(. Can we disable url with lazy loading in ionic 2 ?

Comment: Application doesn't exit, it still goes to the back page. this.platform.exitApp() works fine in apk/iPA but not in PWA.